# Enabling depth testing when using CAOpenGLLayer

Tags: xcode, cocoa, opengl

If one is using a subclass of `NSOpenGLView` then one enables depth testing by selecting a 16/24/32 bit buffer from the attributes menu in Xcode, and then adding

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

to the `drawRect` method. 
 However, in the application I'm creating I'm rendering OpenGL content via the `drawInCGLContext` method of a `CAOpenGLLayer` which is contained within a subclass of `NSView`. This means that it is no longer possible to create a depth buffer via the inspector. Does anyone know how I can achieve this in such a situation?

Comment: glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not as simple as that. I need to first create a depth buffer - this is the part I'm unsure how to do. I'll edit my question to reflect this.

Comment: Hmm... I don't know all the details to answer your question, but here's what I do know. You can create a depth texture by specifying GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT as the format and GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16/24/32 for the internal format. Once you've done that, you can connect it to an FBO via the depth attachment. However, I don't know what CAOpenGLLayer outputs to.